TS path alias not resolving
In main/tsconfig.json I have the following path alias
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./app/*", "./app/src/*"],
      "constants/*": ["./app/src/constants/*"],
    }
  }
}

where main/app/src/constants.js is as follows:
export const test = "abc";

I then try to reference this in main/app/routes/index.tsx as follows:
import {test} from '@constants';
but TS throws the error Cannot find module '@constants' or its corresponding type declarations.
Why is it failing to resolve the type alias and how can I fix this?

Should it be @/constants?

@AdamJenkins The first line "@/*": ["./app/*", "./app/src/*"] is there so I don't have to prepend '@' to each alias.

Are you trying to use it like @(naming), or is it a typo? Because it might need to be used like this: @/(naming).

@gkeenley your matching alias is specified is @/ but your import uses @ which doesn’t match an alias in tsconfig.

Also, I have never seen or realized a syntax where you combine more than one path as an alias. I don’t think it’s a good idea because you might have the same naming in both of your directories, and in that case, I’m not sure what would happen.

Oh, I didn’t see you specified a second alias to constants, that’s weird. You planning on aliasing your whole app?
